# Error when combining two Flux using zipWith

Tags: publish-subscribe, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I am learning the reactive streams and trying to combine the two Flux as follows;

```
        List<Integer> elems = new ArrayList<>();
        Flux.just(10,20,30,40)
            .log()
            .map(x -> x * 2)
            .zipWith(Flux.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE), 
                    (two, one) -> String.format("First  : %d, Second : %d \n", one, two))
            .subscribe(elems::add);
```

and when calling subscribe, i got the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method subscribe(Consumer<? super String>) in the type Flux<String> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (elems::add)
    - The type List<Integer> does not define add(String) that is applicable here
```

and i got the following suggestions to solve the issues:

[image]

But none of these alternative worked.
Any suggestions, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes method references makes you overlook the obvious. I have re-written your function, but with anonymous class.

```
  List<Integer> elems = new ArrayList<>();
    Flux.just(10,20,30,40)
        .log()
        .map(x -> x * 2)
        .zipWith(Flux.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE),
            (two, one) -> String.format("First  : %d, Second : %d \n", one, two))
        .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
          @Override
          public void accept(String s) {

          }
        });
```

I have used code completion from my IDE(intellij) to create this anonymous class. As you can see the input to this consumer is a `String`, which is coming from

```
String.format("First  : %d, Second : %d \n", one, two)
```

So it is complaining that you cannot add a `String` to a `List<Integer>` which is what you are trying to do using `elems:add`